# Invalid Grant on refresh token

Tags: docusignapi

We are using an Authorization Code Grant for our docusign api. When we try to do a refresh request, we get an invalid grant. Does anyone know why we are getting this error? Also, how can we fix and prevent this error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, I don't know docusign but I am here to offer some advice: Question like this go a lot further if we have some code to review and a error message to read.

Comment: Can you please share why you want to use refresh token? are you running a background job for the customer?

Answer (score 0):

As an experiment, try using the refresh token immediately after you first receive it. That will test your refresh token API call. If the refresh fails then you have a problem with your code.

How long after you received the refresh token were you trying to use it?

When you use the refresh token, you receive back a bearer token and a new refresh token. Be sure to use the new refresh token for your next refresh.

Refresh tokens don't last forever, but to get as long-lasting a token as possible, add the scope `extended` to your original request. See [docs.](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/auth_server.html)

Even with extended scope, your refresh token may eventually not work. In those cases you will need to ask your user to log in again.

Answer (score -1):

If refreshtoken would have expired or Authorization header has invalid values then we normally get `invalid_grant` error. There is no specific value which DocuSign gives for Refreshtoken expiry, so I would suggest you to go a better route by following [JWT Service Integration](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/authentication/oa2_jwt.html). Using this you need to get human consent once, then using JWT you can create AccessToken for a user on demand using JWT. You can find more detail demo at [JWT Video](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-developing-docusign-application-authentication/).

Comment: This is a good idea, but this is doing a service integration authentication which Docusign recommends for services that "do not involve a user agent like a browser or web view control". Each user in our application has a unique docusign account.

Comment: DocuSign recommends this approach for both type of integration - User level and Services level. You need to use `User Consent` instead of Admin Consent for your scenario. And `User Consent` uses same flow as your are already using to get AccessToken but now you need to add one more scope 'impersonation' along with signature. This `impersonation` scope help is using JWT to get new AccessToken instead of using RefreshToken.

Comment: @AmitKBist -- Ashwin is correct. If a human is interacting with the app then the app is a User App and it should use Authorization Code Grant or Immediate Grant.

Comment: @LarryK I agree that if human is interacting then it is a UserApp, and they need to start with Authorization Code Grant or Implicit Grant, but what I am suggesting is they can use User Consent flow and add impersonation scope and make use of JWT instead of refresh token. And in future if user wants to revoke the permission then he/she can revoke it also. That way solution does not need to keep on updating refresh token and need not worry about its expiry.

Comment: @AmitKBist -- No, please don't do this. If the user is present, use Auth Code Grant or Implicit Grant. Your method does not allow 2FA or other security enhancements to be added by the end user's InfoSec dept on the fly. JWT flow should only be used when there is no alternative--when users are not available to authenticate themselves.

Comment: @LarryK I am also saying that they should also start with Auth Code Grant or Implicit. But whats the difference between getting new token using JWT or refresh token? Because someone can create a batch job and run it every night or once a week to get new refresh token without user permission and then use this new refresh token to get new access token. So this way refresh token never expires and anytime a new access token can be generates, so kindly help me understand whats the diff between using refresh token or JWT.

Comment: @AmitKBist The difference is that granting permission to the JWT token is a one time deal. After that the JWT token can be used / re-created at anytime. That takes away control of the login security from the administrators. Eg In Jan, Joe grants permission to the JWT. In March his company decides to require Two Factor Logins. The company's decision will not affect Joe since he is no longer logging in--the app is using JWT for him. This is not good. It is not terrible, but it is not recommended. This is the reason why User Apps should try hard to have the user log in.